# Ensure CSV records in Gatling using feeder

Tags: scala, gatling

I have created a simple feeder in Gatling with CSV.
The script is working well and not getting any errors.
I know values are fetching from the CSV during the load test.
But how can I ensure which value is getting for each user.
I have to ensure that first user should login with UserName: user1 and Password: password1.
As I am very very new to Gatling I could not find a solution for this.
Hence please help me to get a solution , Thanks in advance......

My CSV contains-

### Username    Password

user1       password1

user2       password2

user3       password3

And my gatling script for the feeder is:

```
val userCredentails= csv("user_credentials.csv").random 
val scn = scenario("RecordedSimulation")
    .exec(http("request_0")
        .get("/thulasi/myhome.php")
        .headers(headers_0)
        .resources(http("request_1")
        .post(uri1 + "/scripts/index.php")
        .headers(headers_1)
        .formParam("Action", "Offline"),
        http("request_2")
        .get(uri1 + "/images/footer.jpg"),

    .pause(75)
    // Login
      .feed(userCredentails)
    .exec(http("request_3")
        .post("/thulasi/index.php")
        .headers(headers_0)
        .formParam("cand_user_cd", "${Username}")
        .formParam("passwd", "${Password}")
        .resources(http("request_4")
        .post(uri1 + "/scripts/index.php")
        .headers(headers_1)
        .formParam("Action", "Offline"))
        )


setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(3))).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Feeder docs: http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.0/session/feeder.html?highlight=feeders

just don't use random on feeder:

`val userCredentails= csv("user_credentials.csv")`

- this will go from first record to last, and crash when there is no more records in CSV = so you have to be sure your tests won't load more records then you have

or use circular:

`val userCredentails= csv("user_credentials.csv").circular`

- this will go from first to last record, over and over again.

Comment: Is there any way for ensuring the values of ${Username} & ${Password}, like debuging and watching.

Comment: what do you mean by ensuring?

Comment: I want to make sure that  first user is logged with username "user1" and password "password1", second user should logged with username "user2" and password "password2"  etc..  I am looking for some log file if possible, or any other ways.

Comment: as I said, if you drop .random from your feeder it will go in order.

Comment: NP, now just mark my answer correct, and upvote it :)