# Gatling CSV feeder keeps getting the first value in the csv when using repeat() or during() and when using 1 virtual user

Tags: scala, gatling

My question is similar with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188040/ensure-csv-records-in-gatling-using-feeder) one , but he didn't use looping, meanwhile I absolutely need to use it.

My CSV looks simply like this

[image: myCSV.csv]

Using Gatling 3.3.1 , I use 1 user and want to run and repeat a scenario using `during()` , but in each repetition the next CSV value should be taken in sequence. Once it reaches the last value, it should restart to the first value in the CSV.

My codes look like this

```js
val myCSV = csv("data/myCSV.csv").eager.queue.circular

val theScenarioBuilder: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("Test Only")
  .feed(myCSV)
  .during(3 seconds) {
    exec(session => {
      println("myCSV:     " + session("id").as[String])
      session
    })

  }


setUp(
  theScenarioBuilder.inject(atOnceUsers(1))
).protocols(theHttpProtocolBuilder)
```

This will print `myCSV:     1` a couple of times.
My expectation is `myCSV:     1` , `myCSV:     2` , `myCSV:     3` , and so on.

The same when I tried using `repeat()` , I get the same problem, only `myCSV:     1` will be printed.

```js
val myCSV = csv("data/myCSV.csv").eager.queue.circular

val theScenarioBuilder: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("Test Only")
  .feed(myCSV)
  .repeat(3) {
    exec(session => {
      println("myCSV:     " + session("id").as[String])
      session
    })

  }
```

How can I grab different CSV value for each iteration?

Comment: You are reusing one virtual user which got the first row of data in the CSV. Inject more users so that they get the next rows in the CSV.

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't it be possible to use 1 user and feed 20 rows of data to that user? I can do that using JMeter / Postman.  If Gatling can't do that, i.e. if I have 20k rows of CSV data, then I would need to create 20k virtual users , so all my CSV data can be used. That doesn't sound like efficient way of doing data-driven load test, in my opinion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `feed` outside of the `repeat` loop. How could you possibly get different records?

```scala
val myCSV = csv("data/myCSV.csv").eager.circular // queue and circular are exclusive

val theScenarioBuilder: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("Test Only")
  .repeat(3) {
    feed(myCSV)
    .exec(session => {
      println("myCSV:     " + session("id").as[String])
      session
    })

  }
```